# To have underline in two lines?

Tags: line-breaking

Command

```
\underline{bla bla ... bla}
```

The content overflows like so at the moment

[image]

**How can you have underline without overflow to the margin?**

Comment: Don't use underlining for emphasis.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `\uline` from `ulem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document}
 \uline{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a
representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown
elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.
The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic
of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The option `normalem` is passed to prevent `ulem` from under lining the `emph`asised text.

Another option is to use `\ul` from `soul` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
 \ul{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a
representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown
elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.
The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic
of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I always suspected you're a Kantian.

Comment: @egreg hehe, You suspicion is correct :)